# Calling one JQuery from Another

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to marry two jqueries.

Essentially, the following HTML allows user to select a location choice from a dropdown.

```
<select name='location' onchange='changeText(this.value);' required>
        <option value=''>Search by...</option>
        <option value='ZIP Code'>By ZIP Code</option>
        <option value='City Name'>By City Name</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <div id='content'></div>
```

If he selects ZIP code, he is shown a one single field to input ZIP Code.
If he selects City, he is shown two dropdown fields to select city name & state name, using the following scripts:

```
    <script>
    var typeObject = 
    {
        "AZ" : ["Phoenix","Tucson","Mesa"],
        "FL":["Jacksonville","Texas","Tampa"],
        "CL" : ["Aurora","Denver","Springs"],
        Views: ["Name", "Definition", "Owner"]
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            var typeSel = document.getElementById("typeSel"),
                fieldSel = document.getElementById("fieldSel");
            for (var type in typeObject) {
                typeSel.options[typeSel.options.length] = new Option(type, type);
            }
            typeSel.onchange = function () {
                fieldSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
                if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done  
                var ft = typeObject[this.value];
                for (var field in typeObject[this.value]) {
                    fieldSel.options[fieldSel.options.length] = new Option(ft[field], ft[field]);
                }
            }
            typeSel.onchange();
        }
    </script>
<script>
var data = {
    "ZIP Code": "<p><input placeholder=\"ZIPcode...\" name=\"ZIP\" type=\"number\" required oninvalid=\"this.setCustomValidity('Please enter Valid ZIP Code')\" oninput=\"setCustomValidity('')\"></p>",
    "City Name": "<select name=\"st\" id=\"typeSel\" required><option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Pick Your State</option></select><br/><br/><select name=\"ds\" id=\"fieldSel\" required><option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Pick Your City</option></select>"
};

function changeText(id) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data[id];
}
</script>
```

The ZIP Code being a simple text input field is working perfectly.

The City Name has a cascading dropdown menu (like first user selects the state, and then he is shown the list of cities in that selected state). The problem with above code is that it is only showing the two EMPTY drop-downs for state & city with no dropdown values available.

Any help on what is missing in the above code to achieve the state-city cascading drop-down, based on location selection by the user?

Comment: JS console shows: `Uncaught TypeError: typeSel is null`. Can you edit your question to include the relevant HTML?

Comment: Thanks @kmoser - I'm novice in jquery, so not sure what more can be added (unfamiliar with JS console). But my question does have the HTML - typeSel is the "id" of the "state" dropdown field. It is available in the second script in my question - "City Name": "<select name=\"st\" id=\"typeSel\" required><option value=\"\" 
If you are looking for any thing else, please let me know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `window.onload =`

This code *only* runs when the page *first* loads.   At this point the type/field elements don't exist, so your code does nothing.

> `function changeText(id)`

This code adds the elements, but it's too late to populate them so they are empty.

The code within `onload` code just needs to be in `changeText` after you add the elements.

Updated snippet:

```js
var typeObject = {
  "AZ": ["Phoenix", "Tucson", "Mesa"],
  "FL": ["Jacksonville", "Texas", "Tampa"],
  "CL": ["Aurora", "Denver", "Springs"],
  Views: ["Name", "Definition", "Owner"]
}

var data = {
  "ZIP Code": "<p><input placeholder=\"ZIPcode...\" name=\"ZIP\" type=\"number\" required oninvalid=\"this.setCustomValidity('Please enter Valid ZIP Code')\" oninput=\"setCustomValidity('')\"></p>",
  "City Name": "<select name=\"st\" id=\"typeSel\" required><option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Pick Your State</option></select><br/><br/><select name=\"ds\" id=\"fieldSel\" required><option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Pick Your City</option></select>"
};

function changeText(id) {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data[id];
    var typeSel = document.getElementById("typeSel");
  var fieldSel = document.getElementById("fieldSel");
  for (var type in typeObject) {
    typeSel.options[typeSel.options.length] = new Option(type, type);
  }
  typeSel.onchange = function() {
    fieldSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done  
    var ft = typeObject[this.value];
    for (var field in typeObject[this.value]) {
      fieldSel.options[fieldSel.options.length] = new Option(ft[field], ft[field]);
    }
  }
  typeSel.onchange();
}

// Works on initial load as this runs before onload
//changeText("City Name");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='location' onchange='changeText(this.value);' required>
  <option value=''>Search by...</option>
  <option value='ZIP Code'>By ZIP Code</option>
  <option value='City Name'>By City Name</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<div id='content'></div>
```